# Any usage of opengl causes a segmentation fault

Tags: c++, ubuntu, opengl, glut

I'm creating a model loader/viewer in C++ with OpenGL, and am attempting to move my code from Windows(visual studio) to Ubuntu.

Using GDB, I get a segmentation fault:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

The segfault persists even when no glut functions are ever called. This only goes away when I actually remove any mention of glut from the code.

It is my understanding that there are differences between the Microsoft and GNU compiler, as well as different behavior in general for certain libraries between the two OS. However, it is incredibly perplexing that I am getting a segfault at the very start of the program, as opposed to possibly a compilation error.

I've tested that glut works with other programs, use the appropriate glut header for linux (#include ) and make sure to include the glut flags while compiling:

```
main: main.o    g++ -o main main.o -lGL -lGLU -lglut -std=gnu++11

main.o: main.cpp loader.h geom.h    g++ -c main.cpp -lGL -lGLU -lglut
-std=gnu++11
```

Comment: Post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and associated backtrace.

Comment: Do you use GLUT? If not, get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue is a known bug with OpenGL and Ubuntu. Attempting to link String and/or future together with the OpenGL library will cause the program to break.